# Смена картинки fab из кода

Tags: android

У меня в Layout имеется fab, в котором определена картинка

```
<com.google.android.material.floatingactionbutton.FloatingActionButton
        android:id="@+id/fab"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginBottom="@dimen/spacing_normal_16"
        android:layout_marginStart="@dimen/spacing_huge_32"
        android:layout_marginEnd="@dimen/spacing_huge_32"

        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:srcCompat="@drawable/ic_voice_white_24dp" />
```

Как можно изменить эту картинку из кода? Не вижу соответствующего метода

Answer (score 4):

Используйте

```
fab.setImageDrawable(ContextCompat.getDrawable(getContext(), R.drawable.icon))
```

Comment: я думал для srcCompat другой метод, спасибо

Comment: @danilshik если у вас `minSdkVersion 21` и выше можете использовать `src`. 
`srcCompat` для векторных картинок когда `minSdkVersion` ниже 21